# Lookaheads to delimit text

Tags: javascript, regex

I'm trying to delimit  a huge text with several documents inside. Each document starts with the word 'MINISTÉRIO', so i'm trying to use lookaheads to catch everything from MINISTÉRIO until the next MINISTÉRIO:

```
(MINISTÉRIO)[\s\S]*?(^(?=\1))
```

http://regexr.com/3dk6k

I also was trying to:

```
(^MINISTÉRIO)[\s\S]*?(?=\1)
```

http://regexr.com/3dk6h

Nether is working. I have two questions: Why my regex is not working? Should be i think... And, how to fix?

Thanks!

Comment: Why not `.split(/^MINISTÉRIO/m)`?

Comment: I don't have this option, i need use match because is an API @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Is the MINISTERIO  always at the start of a line? Should there be a check if it is a whole word or not? Check https://regex101.com/r/uP6gM0/1

Comment: MINISTERIO is always the start of a doc @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: Check https://regex101.com/r/uP6gM0/1

Comment: Great, is working! Can you post as an answer? Do you know why me code isn't working?

Comment: Does your code execution freeze? I just need to know what issue you have.

Comment: Not really, is just getting one match, when it should catch 2 (i think)..

Comment: I'm trying to understand why my regex isn't working @WiktorStribiżew. Follow me - (MINISTÉRIO)[\s\S]*?(^(?=\1)).

I want catch everything between "MINISTÉRIO", so.. i'm finding the MINISTÉRIO as the first group, than i catch everything until the next MINISTÉRIO as the first word. For me should be working... hahha

Comment: I am feeding my daughter before the bed, I will give an expanded answer when the kids go to bed

Comment: Thanks @WiktorStribiżew

Comment: @D_REIS your selected answer does not correlate to your question.  If you want any reasoning of why something does not work, you should (1) define what is not working about it and (2) define what the expected result should be.  *`Each document starts with the word 'MINISTÉRIO'`* is incorrect because based on your answer, there are other *MINISTÉRIO* that are included as part of the document.  Therefore, something else must delimit your documents.  As Wiktor shows, the first line is part of the same capture group, which is not what your question is asking, but was probably your intent.

Comment: Well, the problem is rather interesting, I see now.

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew if your answer is what he was originally looking for, then your first comment above to split the string, is the best answer.  Only I'd tweak it a bit; he should split on: `/(\r\n|\n)+(?:MINISTÉRIO)/gm`, which suggests every new document starts with MINISTÉRIO on a new line.  However, there are embedded -what looks like mainframe- jobs with commas in front of them.  He should clarify those are not the beginning of a document.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

## Issue Description

The `/(MINISTÉRIO)[\s\S]*?(^(?=\1))/gm` matches the word `MINISTÉRIO` *at any place in the text* capturing it into Group 1. `[\s\S]*?` matches lazily any character, 0 or more repetitions up to a beginning of a line that is followed with the word `MINISTÉRIO`. Thus, **if you have a "document" from some place in the string up to the end, that match won't be found as you cannot specify the `$` anchor since it is redefined to match the end of a *line*.**

Using `/(^MINISTÉRIO)[\s\S]*?(?=\1)/g`, you match and capture the `MINISTÉRIO` word at the beginning of the whole string only, and match any char as few as possible up to the first `MINISTÉRIO` substring in the string, at any place in the string, and there is no check for the beginning of a line.

## Solution

You may use an unrolled regex like

```
/^MINISTÉRIO\b.*(?:\n(?!MINISTÉRIO\b).*)*/gm
```

The [regex demo is here](https://regex101.com/r/uP6gM0/2)

When the text is too long, lazy matching like in your pattern takes too much time, and using negated character classes can greatly increase performance.

In short:

- `^MINISTÉRIO\b` - matches `MINISTÉRIO` as a whole word at the start of a line:

  - `^` - start of a line (due to `/m` modifier)
  - `MINISTÉRIO\b` - a whole word `MINISTÉRIO` as `\b` is a word boundary
- `.*(?:\n(?!MINISTÉRIO\b).*)*` - matches any text that is not `MINISTÉRIO` at the start of a line:

  - `.*` - 0+ chars other than a newline
  - `(?:\n(?!MINISTÉRIO\b).*)*` - 0+ sequences of:
  - `\n(?!MINISTÉRIO\b)` - a newline not followed with `MINISTÉRIO` as a whole word
  - `.*` - 0+ chars other than a newline

It is basically the same as [`/^MINISTÉRIO\b(?:(?!^MINISTÉRIO\b)[\s\S])*/gm`](https://regex101.com/r/uP6gM0/1), but should be much faster as the *tempered greedy token* (`(?:(?!^MINISTÉRIO\b)[\s\S])*`) is rather resource consuming.